# Reducing Coupling Between Test Cases

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, tdd

I am trying to learn more about JUnit and TDD, but I am running into some issues with coupling between test cases.

When I am writing a test case for a particular data type's API, say a `Deque<T>`, how can I limit the coupling between the test cases?  For instance, if I were writing a test case for the method `insertFirst(T item)`, it seems straightforward to assume that I should be able to assert two things after calling the method on a properly initialized object:

1. The size of the `Deque` object should have increased by one
2. If I subsequently call the corresponding `T removeFirst()` method , it should return a reference to the object I inserted with the initial call.

However, this creates an undesirable coupling between at least two of my test cases, where one test case passing depends on the correct implementation of another API method.  For instance, in order for this test case to pass, I would need a correct implementation for checking the number of items in the `Deque` and also for removing items.  If my test for either of those methods was incorrect or incomplete for whatever reason, then my test for the `insertFirst` method would automatically be suspect.

What are best practices for avoiding this scenario?  Is my approach to writing test cases wrong in some way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When writing a test for one method, you *have* to assume that the rest of class is working correctly. If you wouldn't make this assumption, the only conclusion would be a single, *massive* test per class. And that's not what we do.

You can make the assumption that the other parts of the class work correctly, because there will be tests for those other parts, too, ensuring their correctness.
If one part is not working correctly, a test will fail, showing you that something is not correct.
As soon as a test of your test suite fails, there is an error you have to fix. You no longer can make any assumptions.

Example:

You have a simple list implementation with only three methods:

1. insert
2. remove
3. count

You have three tests:

1. Test for `insert`:

   - create instance of list (*Arrange*)
   - `insert` item (*Act*)
   - check that `count` equals 1 (*Assert*)
2. Test for `remove`:

   - create instance of list and `insert` item (*Arrange*)
   - `remove` item (*Act*)
   - check that `count` equals 0 (*Assert*)
3. Test for `count`:

   - create instance of list and `insert` n items (*Arrange*)
   - retrieve `count` (*Act*)
   - check that `count` equals n (*Assert*)

Now, if any of the above tests fail, you can't be sure of the correctness of a singlemember of your class:

- If the first test fails, the third one will also fail. The second one will pass, but didn't actually test `remove`, because there was nothing to remove.
- If the second test fails, the other two tests will still pass. Still, you can't be sure that `insert` and `count` are working correctly, because the second test will fail if any of the three members doesn't work correctly.
- If the third test failes, the other two most likely will fail, too.

The failing tests tell you something though:
Depending on the tests that fail, you often can deduct where the error has to be.
Example: If only the second test fails but not the first or third, the error most likely is in the `remove` method.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but doesn't this create a circular dependency of methods?  In order to test insert, I have to use remove, and in order to test remove, I have use insert?  This seems wrong somehow.  It may be that I just do not have enough experience with the ideas and I'll soon grow comfortable with being uncomfortable.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @crlane: Yes, it creates some sort of circular dependency. That's why you can't say *anything* about your class if even one test failes. Only if *all* tests pass, you know that everything works as expected.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense.  So my error was in how I was interpreting the passing of a single test case.  If a test for a single method passes, it does _NOT_ mean the method is correct.  I can only assume that my method is correct if I have written a complete test suite that tests **all** the methods of the API correctly.  That helps.  Thanks again.

Comment: @crlane: Exactly, now you got it! :)

Comment: +1, i would add that one of the things you are testing for is unexpected side effects of method calls, so test dependencies on other methods are not just tolerable but useful.

Answer (score 4):

It is generally more productive to think of unit tests as testing particular features rather than particular methods.  Any given test will check that some collection of methods works correctly to implement the feature that is the subject of the test, and the pattern of failure in a well-designed set of tests will tend to tell you which method broke fairly quickly.

A good collection of tests tends to fall naturally out of doing TDD; that's one of the things that makes the technique so powerful.  If I'm writing a `Deque`, the tests I write will tend to be the following, generally presenting in this order.

1. `empty_Deque_isEmpty` -- implement `isEmpty` to always return `true`
2. `non_empty_Deque_isntEmpty` -- implement `insertFirst` to make `isEmpty` instance variable false
3. `re_emptied_Deque_isEmpty` -- change instance variable used by `isEmpty` to be a number that responds to `insertFirst` and `removeFirst`
4. `is_empty_Deque_size_correct` -- implement `size` to always return 0
5. `is_nonempty_Deque_size_correct` -- add instance variable to track size; realize it's doing the same thing needed by `isEmpty`; refactor
6. `is_re_emptied_Deque_size_correct` -- have the test just pass because of what we did to make 5. happen
7. `does_removing_from_empty_Deque_throw` -- `removeFirst` needs to check `size` before doing anything else
8. `is_inserted_item_returned` -- `insertFirst` and `removeFirst` now populate a `T` instance variable
9. `is_inserted_item_returned_from_end` -- add `removeLast` that is a copy of `removeFirst`; refactor
10. `is_rear_inserted_item_returned` -- add `insertLast` that copies `insertFirst`; refactor
11. `are_all_inserted_items_returned` -- change `insertFirst` and `removeFirst` to act on `SomeKindOfCollection<T>`; make a point of not checking order of retrieval
12. `does_removeFirst_retrieve_items_in_correct_order` -- insert two things, make sure the second one is returned by `removeFirst`.  Might already be true.
13. `does_removeLast_retrieve_items_in_correct_order` -- ditto for `removeLast`, except pretty certain not to already pass.

That's a whole bunch of tests, but as you look through them you should notice the pattern.  None of these tests is really "the test for `count`" or "the test for `removeFirst`".  But by the time we're through, the entire interface of the class is being exercised and all the internals necessary to that interface have been developed.  Some of the tests depend on more than one method and if that method should fail, they will all break.  But the pattern of breaks will tend to be very helpful in determining where the bug is.

Also interesting is how many of these tests we can make pass without ever needing to commit to actually having a collection in the object, which suggests that that set of tests could be factored out into a more general test suite which will be useful when developing `PriorityQueue`.

Comment: +1 I fully agree on "testing particular features rather than particular methods". I though about bringing that into my answer as well but I had the feeling it would overwhelm the OP. Glad you brought it up!